# How To Make Website in local web server (XAMPP) Can Be Accessed Via Internet

Tags: xampp

I have completed website development for my personal business. I have a server and it's ip public 202.x.x.x.
I install XAMPP in server(ip public 202.x.x.x.) and then upload my web script in there.

Now my question is:
-How to make my web can be accessed via internet? (example, web can be accessed via ip http://202.x.x.x)
and
-How to make my web can be accessed via internet by name? (example, web can be accessed by http://www.mybiz.net)

Please give me an explaination, step by step, to solve this case.

Comment: It seems I have to answer my question myself :). Fisrtly, maybe because this is not programming question that cause no answer and less view. But I dont delete this post cos I think there are someone out there that face the same problem.

Comment: Based on my experiment, to get your local site go public (can accessed via internet) than you must have min 1 ip public (you can get this by your ISP Web Host/Data Center). And then you must set your localhost to this ip public and set your domain refer to that's ip public (google it to find the way). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Cpanel / DNS account and update the A record to point that that ip .

eg:- yourwebsite.com A record to your IP .

This way when any when searches for your website, it points to the IP address of your server.

1) Having xamp open to the whole world is not reaally recommended as it is used usually for local development 
2) You need to configure appropriate port on the router and point it to your machines IP 
3) Hopefully your ISP provides you with a static IP

Would surely recommend to get a hosting accounting.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver host should be a static ip to be accessed via Internet. There is another method, a web tunneling tool which comes handy named - `ngrok.` Please check `ngrok` documentation